# Create sequence from literal variable inputs

Tags: linux, bash, shell, brace-expansion

I'm trying to create sequences as follows:

```
startDay=1
endDay=2
dayRange="{$startDay..$endDay}"
echo \[\"$dayRange\",\"{00..02}\"\]
```

The output is:

```
["{1..2}","00"] ["{1..2}","01"] ["{1..2}","02"]
```

When specifying the sequence directly `{00..02}`, it auto creates `"00", "01", "02"`, but it does not understand the `dayRange` variable.
What I expect it to return is:

```
["1","00"] ["1","01"] ["1","02"] ["2","00"] ["2","01"] ["2","02"]
```

Not sure what I missed.
Please advise.

Comment: Brace expansion happens **before** parameter expansion. By the time `$startDay` and `$endDay` are replaced with actual values, `{1..2}`-style expansions are no longer being run.

Comment: While there are ugly hacks with `eval`, the sane/reliable/robust thing is to simply _not do that_; loop over the numeric range you want to process with a `for` loop. See https://ideone.com/TZoJxp for an example.

Comment: BTW -- see discussion of this issue in [BashPitfalls #33](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.7B1...24n.7D)

Comment: I see, thank you @CharlesDuffy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea would be a simple nested `for` loop:

```
startDay=1
endDay=2

pfx=
out=

for ((i=startDay; i<=endDay; i++))
do
    for j in {00..02}
    do
         out+="${pfx}[\"${i}\",\"${j}\"]"
         pfx=" "
    done
done

echo "${out}"
```

This generates:

```
["1","00"] ["1","01"] ["1","02"] ["2","00"] ["2","01"] ["2","02"]
```

---

A bit less coding, and a bit faster, which uses OP's `echo ... {00..02}` to eliminate one of the `for` loops:

**NOTE:** this eliminates the subprocess `$(echo ...)` call I had in a previous edit.

```
startDay=1
endDay=2

for ((i=startDay; i<=endDay; i++))
do
    echo -n "[\""${i}"\",\""{00..02}"\"]"
    echo -n " "
done

echo ""
```

This also generates:

```
["1","00"] ["1","01"] ["1","02"] ["2","00"] ["2","01"] ["2","02"]
```

---

Here's one `awk` idea:

```
awk -v start=$"${startDay}" -v end="${endDay}" '
BEGIN {
    pfx=""
    out=""

    for (i=start; i<=end; i++)
        for (j=0; j<=2; j++) {
             out=out pfx "[\"" i "\",\"" sprintf("%02d", j) "\"]"
             pfx=" "
        }
    print out
}'
```

This also generates:

```
["1","00"] ["1","01"] ["1","02"] ["2","00"] ["2","01"] ["2","02"]
```

---

With the elimination of the earlier subprocess `$(echo ...)` the first 2 solutions come in with single-digit millisecond timings while the `awk` solution comes in with low double-digit millisecond timings.

As the number of days (and/or sequence size) increases the first 2 solutions start taking longer (the nested `for` loop falling farther behind) while the `awk` solution tends to maintain the same speed.

For really large increases (number of days and/or sequence size) I would expect `awk` to close in on, and eventually take, the lead.